# HLS FLAC stream using FFMPEG

Tags: ffmpeg, http-live-streaming, flac

I have created a HLS stream from a FLAC file with an output of FLAC using the following command:

```
ffmpeg 
    -i 10-brass-in-pocket.flac 
    -map 0:a -c:a:0 flac 
    -f hls 
    -hls_playlist_type vod 
    -master_pl_name master.m3u8 
    -hls_time 30 
    -hls_segment_type fmp4 
    -strict -2  
    -hls_segment_filename music.m4s 
    -hls_flags single_file  
    -var_stream_map "a:0" stream_%v.m3u8`
```

I have published it here:

https://di5wym8npn4cm.cloudfront.net/stackoverflow_fmp4_singlefile/master.m3u8. (this works in VLC)

Page with audio controls here:

https://di5wym8npn4cm.cloudfront.net/stackoverflow_fmp4_singlefile/index.html

I can see from the network tab in Safari that the second segment fails with a http code 206.

Why does this stream not play?

Comment: yep, I'm look at that now.  Do you know what it should be? I also tried audio/mp4; codecs="flac"

Comment: thx..but no dice :/ frustrating thing is the browser says error but can't find details anywhere that would provide a clue

Comment: I get the same error with my own encoded stream and correct MIME types so it must be something else. Can't find an official sample HLS/FLAC stream to test.